# ubuntu one problem

Tags: ubuntu-one

Today I logged into my ubuntu one account using my webbrowser and after that i saw a screen prompting me to accept some kind of extension of my cloud space to 5 gb. After accepting this, I was unable to find the files I previously uploaded to my ubuntu one acc.
So, i'd like to now whether/where can I get my files?

P.S.
I don't know whether this matters or not but I haven't visited my account for a long time.
Oh, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For problems like this, your best bet is to contact our support guys with this form:

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

Be sure to use the email address associated with your Ubuntu One account so that they know what account is in use.

It is possible that you've created a second account here, so if there are other email addresses you use, it couldn't hurt to mention them in the message.